# Building Django app with base map to plot data on from database

Tags: python, maps, gis, geodjango

I'm trying to build an app in my django project, where i will have database with coordinates and other data concerning each location, and i'm not able to find a way in Django.

I'm have seen too many complications PostGIS and Spatialite and couldn't find some tutorial that builds something similar.

Any simple way to do that?

Comment: Here are some tutorials to start working with geospatial using postgresql https://realpython.com/location-based-app-with-geodjango-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that most of them assume that I'm using MAC while I'm on windows and i get pretty much locked because of differences within systems...
thank you anyway

Comment: I looked at the tutorial, have you tried using npm instead of aptitude for installing packages?